# How to customize tableView edit mode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

So apple provides the edit mode which looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to use custom icons for "red circle" and "hamburger menu"? Also to change "x" or "y" position?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom edit view in UITableViewCell while swipe left. Objective-C or Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left-objective-c-or-swift)

Comment: No way, Use custom.

Comment: The "red circle" is using to delete the entire row in iOS default. Do you need this action ?? If no, then you can hide the red icon and by designing your custom cell you can get table cell with round icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When putting a `UITableView`in editing mode using `setEditing(_:animated:)`, “the table view goes into editing mode by calling `setEditing(_:animated:)` on each visible UITableViewCell object” according to [Apple’s `UITableView`documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614876-setediting). You could create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `setEditing(_:animated:)` there, using custom image views holding your versions of the circle and hamburger symbols inside your cell’s XIB.

Answer (score 0):

I found helpful [the code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56647564/5222821) although only when calling it in `layoutSubviews()`.